# .idea files in intellij

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I was wondering why this folder is included in all projects that I make in intellij IDE? I've made a small bootstrap project that I would like to upload on a server. When I do, will these files also be uploaded. On my machine the files are hidden (mac), unless I explicitly make them visible (the entire folder is hidden).

Here is a screenshot of my project:

[image]

So there are a few xml files and one .name txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This folder contains all the files for the project specific configurations.

Check which scope you defined above the tree files:

[image]

When Project Files is selected, all the folder will be displayed.
Select Project will automatically hide the .idea folder.

If you use a version control soft, this folder is automatically excluded.

EDIT:
You can exclude files you'll upload to the server in Project Settings->Deployment->Options:

[image]

I think the .idea folder is excluded by default. You need this folder locally to open you PHPStorm project correctly, but you don't need it on your web server.

Comment: Some VCS might automatically ignore it, but some you must either tell the VCS to ignore it (e.g. .gitignore) or have the IDE explicitly ignore it for version control.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But you did not answer my main question (or maybe I'm a little bit thick), but when I upload my project on a server, is the .idea folder included? Do I need this folder, or can I delete it when uploading. It takes a little bit of space...